# Questions about overdamping, critical damping and underdamping

Tags: oscillators, differential-equations, applied-physics

I am a math lecturer and in my teaching of second-order linear differential equations I present, as an application, the classical mass-spring-dashpot system (and its RLC analogue). According to my understanding, if the overdamping case modelled an automobile suspension system, the ride would be uncomfortable. Furthermore, critical damping represents the minimum damping that can be applied to the physical system without causing oscillation.

One textbook I use (Ordinary Differential Equations and Applications by Weighfer and Lindsay) says:
*(Critical damping) is often the desired configuration for practical aplications since it represents the weakest damping before oscillatory becomes possible.*

Nevertheless, another textbook I use (Differential Equations for Engineers by Xie) states that:
*Most engineering structures fall in this category (i.e. underdamping
case) with (the dimensionless) damping coeffient $\zeta$ usually less
than $10\%$.*
[$\zeta=\frac{\gamma}{2\sqrt{mk}}$ for the mechanical system; $\zeta=\frac{2}{R}\sqrt{\frac{C}{L}}$ for the electrical analogue].

Question 1: Which author is right?

Question 2: In general What are some practical applications where each case (heavy, critical and light damping) is desirable or not desirable?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Couldn't both authors be right? If vibrations are potential problem for a structure, it makes sense to add some damping to prevent oscillations. On the other hand, without specific damping design, most structures are not dampened enough by default (I think steel has damping below 2 %).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If damping factor is a design driver, you'll usually choose damping close to critical. It is often true that given the parameters you can control, less damping leads to a faster response of the system to disturbance, so you may choose damping a bit less than critical.

On the other hand, it may be perfectly acceptable for the system to ring, and adding friction may be undesirable. Or, the design of a high inertia system may naturally lead to overdamping.